# Scrapy running consecutively not concurrently

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I have a spider that takes a list of addresses and requests information from a single page sending an address and some session information as a scrapy.FormRequest. However, the scraper seems to be running them consecutively. I can tell this because if you search 10 addresses it takes 17 seconds and if you search 20 addresses it takes double the time at about 32 seconds. Since the biggest delay is just waiting for the response, and there's no complex parsing going on, if it was running concurrently, it should just take a little longer correct?

I've tried making sure concurrent requests was set high enough in the settings.py. I have added dont_filter = true to the form request. But still can't seem to get it to work. It should also be noted that the scraper is working in the sense that it does pull the information requested.

settings.py

```
CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_DOMAIN = 20
CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_IP = 20
CONCURRENT_REQUESTS = 20
```

main.py

```
class WaterSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "water"
def __init__(self,stats):
    dispatcher.connect(self.spider_closed, signals.spider_closed)
    self.stats = stats 
@classmethod 
def from_crawler(cls, crawler): 
  return cls(crawler.stats)
def start_requests(self):
    #Pull saved session ID Info
    with open('items.json') as f:
        sessioninfo = json.load(f)
    sessioninfo = sessioninfo[0]

    url = 'http://cityservices.baltimorecity.gov/water/'

    #Take the cookies from what was scraped above and add them to the new cookies to be passed.
    cookies = {
        'popup':'seen',
        'ASP.NET_SessionId': sessioninfo['sessioncookie']
    }
    #Same with the different view states.
    post_params = {
        '__VIEWSTATE':  sessioninfo['VIEWSTATE'],
        '__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR': sessioninfo['VIEWSTATEGENERATOR'],
        '__EVENTVALIDATION': sessioninfo['EVENTVALIDATION'],
        'ctl00$ctl00$rootMasterContent$LocalContentPlaceHolder$btnGetInfoServiceAddress': 'Get Info'
    }

    #Run through all the addresses in our csv to start scraping.
    with open('Addresses.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
        addresses = csv.reader(csvfile)
        for x,row in enumerate(addresses):
            self.log("Row " + str(x))
            address = row[0]
            post_params['ctl00$ctl00$rootMasterContent$LocalContentPlaceHolder$ucServiceAddress$txtServiceAddress']= address
            yield scrapy.FormRequest(url=url, callback=self.parseWaterBill, cookies = cookies, method='POST',formdata=post_params, meta={'address':address,'timestamp':datetime.today(),'row_num':str(x)},errback=self.errback_httpbin,dont_filter = True)
```

Output

```
/app/WaterBill/spiders/main.py:16: ScrapyDeprecationWarning: Importing from 
scrapy.xlib.pydispatch is deprecated and will no longer be supported in 
future Scrapy versions. If you just want to connect signals use the 
from_crawler class method, otherwise import pydispatch directly if needed. 
See: https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/issues/1762
from scrapy.xlib.pydispatch import dispatcher
2018-09-09 15:02:28 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 1.5.1 started (bot: 
WaterBill)
2018-09-09 15:02:28 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Versions: lxml 4.2.4.0, libxml2 
2.9.8, cssselect 1.0.3, parsel 1.5.0, w3lib 1.19.0, Twisted 18.7.0, Python 
3.6.6 (default, Jul 17 2018, 11:12:33) - [GCC 6.3.0 20170516], pyOpenSSL 
18.0.0 (OpenSSL 1.1.0i  14 Aug 2018), cryptography 2.3.1, Platform Linux- 
4.9.93-linuxkit-aufs-x86_64-with-debian-9.5
2018-09-09 15:02:28 [scrapy.crawler] INFO: Overridden settings: {'BOT_NAME': 
'WaterBill', 'CONCURRENT_REQUESTS': 20, 'CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_DOMAIN': 
20, 'CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_IP': 20, 'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 
'WaterBill.spiders', 'ROBOTSTXT_OBEY': True, 'SPIDER_MODULES': 
['WaterBill.spiders']}
2018-09-09 15:02:28 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats',
'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
'scrapy.extensions.memusage.MemoryUsage',
'scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats']
2018-09-09 15:02:28 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled downloader 
middlewares:
['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.robotstxt.RobotsTxtMiddleware',
'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',
'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware',
'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware',
'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats']
2018-09-09 15:02:28 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
2018-09-09 15:02:28 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
[]
2018-09-09 15:02:28 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2018-09-09 15:02:28 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 
pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2018-09-09 15:02:28 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] DEBUG: Telnet console 
listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
```

End of Output

```
2018-09-09 15:03:01 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2018-09-09 15:03:01 [water] DEBUG: Scraped 19 in 0:00:32.526211 seconds
2018-09-09 15:03:01 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 198397,
'downloader/request_count': 21,
'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 1,
'downloader/request_method_count/POST': 20,
'downloader/response_bytes': 2057507,
'downloader/response_count': 21,
'downloader/response_status_count/200': 21,
'finish_reason': 'finished',
'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2018, 9, 9, 15, 3, 1, 223408),
'item_scraped_count': 19,
'log_count/DEBUG': 62,
'log_count/INFO': 7,
'memusage/max': 51474432,
'memusage/startup': 51474432,
'response_received_count': 21,
'scheduler/dequeued': 20,
'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 20,
'scheduler/enqueued': 20,
'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 20,
'start_time': datetime.datetime(2018, 9, 9, 15, 2, 28, 697197)}
2018-09-09 15:03:01 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```